# Remaking MFC dialog for using tab control

Tags: tabs, mfc

I have an MFC applicaton, but now i need to add new features using tab control(so my main program dialog become "tab 1"). But there is a problem I see - when using tabs, you must create new application and then add tabs as dialogs. So it means I need to rewrite all the event handlers for buttons and all variables i used in my project. Is there a way to migrate to tabcontrol application without doing so much job again?

Comment: is it a must to use tab control? you could use CPropertySheet, that will contain CPropertyPage, so each CPropertyPage would be your dialog and you can even use the templates you already have for the dialogs on the pages, also the handlers don't need to be changed, but you will have to substitute the CDialog class with CPropertyPage

Comment: Looks really good but not what i want. This is a helpful comment, but I still must use tabs.

Comment: You can use the same dialog, but create it as child dialog, and then fit it inside `CPropertyPage`. Or put the child dialog inside a main dialog, and show/hide it with a tab control. I think that's basically what Robson said, point being that you don't have to start over.

Comment: CPropertyPage is not really thing I need I think, because i need to have some common elements and handlers for all tabs on dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to rewrite the event handlers. I used the [CMFCTabCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984302.aspx) class and all event handlers still continue to be inside the forms they were.

It is very practical, as unlike the old CTabCtrl, you do not need to make code to hide/show elements when switching tabs. You just have to pass a CWnd* typed variable when you do AddTab(), and that variable could be ... your form.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i've already rebuilt my application. :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you used the old CTabCtrl, it is worth it to migrate it to the CMFCTabCtrl.